# Rails rake task to change column values in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, postgresql

A tabel in my pgsql database has a column named "duration" which currently stores a string such as.. "5m 21s".. meaning 5 minutes and 21 seconds.

I am creating a rake task to reformat these to just be the total amount of seconds.

So "5m 21s" would become "321".

... right now I could write something such as this but I am unsure how to build the query itself.

```
desc 'Change call duration format'
task calls_format_fix: :environment do

    # Service::CallsReport.where('duration')... 
    # all nums before 'm' * 60 + nums before 's'.. then remove all alpha characters.. (do this with regex? ([0-9]*)m\s+([0-9]*)s)

end
```

Comment: Are you asking how to execute ActiveRecord queries inside a rake task, or how to build your query?

Comment: correct, how to build the query.

Comment: I know I could use regex like: `([0-9]*)m\s+([0-9]*)s`.. if I do this I will need to store all the values first I assume and loop through them and then update them.

Comment: Are you changing the column type at the same time?

Comment: No I won't need to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! This is my code and query with comments of what I am doing to achieve changing the column values. Not sure that this is the best solution but it works!

```
desc 'Change call duration format from minutes and seconds to just seconds' 
task calls_reformat: :environment do

   #store all calls in durationValues
   durationValues = Service::CallsReport.all

   #loop through each as 'call'
   durationValues.each do |call|

     #regex to capture minutes and seconds
     call.duration.match(/([0-9]*)m\s+([0-9]*)s/)

     #store the first match ($1) and multiply it by 60 in minToSec
     minToSec = $1.to_i * 60

     #add minToSec to matched seconds from regex ($2)
     totalValue = minToSec + $2.to_i

     #update the value of call duration
     call.update(duration: totalValue)
   end
end
```